# CSS: Scale items when resizing in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with this issue for a while now, so I hope someone can help.

For example:

```
<section class="example-a"> 
    <ol>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="cell">A</li>
        <li class="cell">B</li>
        ....
        <li class="spacer"></li>
   </ol>
</section>
```

If I resize `.example-a` by 40% I want each `li` to shrink by 40%. Meaning that if the `.spacer` is twice as big as the `.cell` it will keep that ratio when resizing. Checkout the first `section` in this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/13/). If you resize you see that from the beginning each elements shrinks or grows.

It behaves as I want, except that I want to visualise it differently; the `ol` needs to be visualised as a group. Checkout the second `section` in the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/13/). But whatever I do, when I resize, first the `.spacer` elements shrink before the `ol`.

Any suggestion how I can fix this or maybe work around it?

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-a, 
.example-b {
    display: flex; 
    border: 2px solid blue;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    ol {
         list-style-type: none;
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100%;
       
       .cell {
             border: 1px solid #000;
             width: 100px;
             height: 100px;
             
            
               //display: flex;
               align-items: center;
               justify-content: center;
             
         }
     }
       
    
     .spacer {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: green;
            
            &:first-child {
              width: 400px;
            }
        }
}

.example-b {
  ol {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section class="example-a"> 
    <ol>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li class="cell">A</li>
        <li class="cell">B</li>
        <li class="cell">D</li>
        <li class="cell">D</li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
    </ol>
</section>

<section class="example-b">
    <span class="spacer"></span>  
    <ol>
        <li class="cell"><span>A</span></li>
        <li class="cell"><span>B</span></li>
        <li class="cell"><span>C</span></li>
        <li class="cell"><span>D</span></li>
    </ol>
    <span class="spacer"></span>  
</section>
</main>
```

UPDATE: Although most answers are useful and tackle the issue in a way, I've chosen the answer which helped me the most for my particular case

Comment: Something along these lines? https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/16/

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple: you simply have to declare an explicit width in the `<ol>` in your second example. This will force the nested `<ol>` to shrink when the viewport is narrower than what can be fitted on the screen:

```
.example-b {
  ol {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 40%;  /* Added this rule */
  }
}
```

See updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/tjtp5403/17/

Comment: I'm not sure yet if `%` will work in my case, so do you think it can be done using `px`?

Comment: Whatever that floats your boat: the suggested percentage is simply used because you wanted your second example to match the first.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you're after. If so, your code can be simplified.

[revised fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/16/)

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
       
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;  
}

ol::before, ol::after {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  content: "";
}

ol::before {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="cell">A</li>
  <li class="cell">B</li>
  <li class="cell">D</li>
  <li class="cell">D</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you give the `cell` `flex: 1 1 0` and the `spacer` `flex: 2 2 0`, the `spacer` will always be twice the size of the `cell`  (`flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`)

This work like that, that as `spacer` has *flex-grow: 2* and `cell` has *flex-grow: 1*, the `spacer` will take twice the available space, and as the *flex-basis* is set to *0*, the content in each flex item will not affect how the available space will be distributed.

The same works for the `flex-shrink` when there is a negative space.
I also added `min-width: 0`, which will allow the items to shrink beyond its content, so the aspect ratio will be maintained when the content won't fit the flex container. (and if the content overflow/overlap, use `overflow: hidden` instead of `min-width: 0`)

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/23/)

Stack snippet

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-a {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.example-a ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-a ol .cell {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}

.example-a ol .spacer {
  flex: 2 2 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="example-a">
    <ol>
      <li class="spacer"></li>
      <li class="cell">A</li>
      <li class="cell">B</li>
      <li class="cell">D</li>
      <li class="cell">D</li>
      <li class="spacer"></li>
    </ol>
  </section>
</main>
```

---

Updated

If the sole purpose of the `spacer` is to simply be just that, a *spacer*, you can use the pseudo elements instead, like this (I also simplified the code a little)

[Updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/24/)

Stack snippet

```css
.example-a {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.example-a ol {
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example-a ol .cell,
.example-a ol::before,
.example-a ol::after {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}

.example-a ol .cell {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.example-a ol::before,
.example-a ol::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  flex: 2 2 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="example-a">
  <ol>
    <li class="cell">A</li>
    <li class="cell">B</li>
    <li class="cell">D</li>
    <li class="cell">D</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

---

If you want it to work with IE, the *flex-basis* value need a unit, i.e. `0px`

[Updated fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtp5403/25/)